# How to use a reference multiple times just to do the stuff in a single sentence?

Tags: java

I have the code shown below.

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(Integer.toBinaryString(n));

return (sb.charAt(sb.length() - k) == '1') ? Integer.parseInt(sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - k).insert(sb.length() - (k + 1), 0).toString(),2) : n;
```

Is it possible to use the`sb` reference implicitly, i.e. just in order to write only the return sentence?

Comment: Even if it is possible you should not do it because it takes a couple of minutes to read / understand the code and you do not ever want that to happen.

Comment: I agree with luk2303: this code is *very* convoluted for being placed on a single line. Writing that as an explicit it-then with explicit returns and well-named variables doesn't hurt performance at all and makes reading the code **much** easier. And **if** performance is the goal here, then getting rid of the int-to-binary-string conversion and replacing the operation with the appropriate bit fiddling will likely speed everything up massively.

Comment: Instead of asking how you could make this overly-complex one-liner even more unreadable, perhaps you should write it more normally as an `if`/`else` statement across multiple lines, where each line does one easily-understandable thing, and meaningful values are assigned to named variables.

Comment: Thank you all of you guys for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way you can "implicitly" use such a reference is when a method returns `this` (i.e. the object you call it on) to allow that kind of call chaining. For example [`StringBuilder.deleteCharAt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#deleteCharAt(int)) does this and you already make use of this by chaining a call to `insert`:

```
sb.deleteCharAt(...).insert(...)
```

This kind of return value only makes sense in method that don't have any other return value to give (i.e. you obviously can't do that with `sb.charAt`, because that returns a `char` and can't *also* return the `StringBuilder` itself).

But if you want to know if you can get rid of the `sb` in `sb.length()` for example: no, you pretty much can't.

Comment: Thank you Joachim!.. This is an exercise "on bits" and I think I will approach another way, however I learnt from your comments.